# Printing bits in long long number (C++)

Tags: c++, bit, long-long

I want to print all bits of a long long number.
When I am doing it in main() everything is fine, but in printBits() function (where code is same) there is an extra 1 on 32th bit.

The code:

```
#include <iostream>

void printBits(long long number)
{
    std::cout<<number<<" -> ";
    for (char i=63; i>=0; --i)
    {
        std::cout<<(bool)(number&(1<<i));
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    long long number=1;

    std::cout<<number<<" -> ";
    for (char i=63; i>=0; --i)
    {
        std::cout<<(bool)(number&(1<<i));
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;

    printBits(number);

    return 0;
}
```

Result is:

```
1 -> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001
1 -> 0000000000000000000000000000000100000000000000000000000000000001

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.012 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: I suspect the problem has something to do with `1 << i` being an `int` not a `long long`

Comment: Confirmed -- using ((long long)1) in place of 1 fixes the problem.

Comment: Besides the fix with `1ll`, why is the result in `main()` different from the one in `printBits()`?

Comment: `std::cout << std::bitset<64>(number) << std::endl;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The literal 1 defaults to an integer. Cast it to long long to solve the problem.

```
std::cout<<(bool)(number&(((long long)1)<<i));
```

Comment: `(bool)(number&(1ll << i));` would suffice. The `ll` suffix denotes a `long long`.

Comment: This answer could be improved by explaining why using an `int` doesn't work.

Comment: @GillBates Are you sure you changed both uses of `1 << i`?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yes, this fixed it.

Comment: Maybe it's worth to explain in your answer that 1 is an integer, and that's why (1<<i) is UB according to the standard when i is 32 or more ([expr.shift] *"The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater than or equal to the length in bits of the promoted left operand"*)

Answer (score 3):

As Cpp plus 1's answer shows you need to modify the (default int) literal  `1` to a long long literal `1LL` or `1ll`.

However, you might be better off using `std::bitset` instead of your function:

```
#include <bitset>
long long number = 1;  // int number = 1;  also works
std::bitset<64> bits(number);
std::cout << number << " -> " << bits << std::endl;
```

yields:

> 1 -> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001

The reason you are getting this output is because for the specific hardware/compiler you are using:

`a << x`   operation works in the following way: `a << (x mod (8 * sizeof(a))`. Therefore for `1` you get 
`1 << (x mod 32)`. This means that on the 32nd loop iteration:

```
std::cout << (bool)(number & (1 << 32));
// becomes
std::cout << (bool)(number & (1 << 0));
// printing '1'
```

Comment: I don't believe your explanation is correct since the same code is producing 2 different results.  If what you said was true both loops would give the same thing.

Comment: @NathanOliver is correct. The truth is that the asker invoked undefined behavior.

Comment: @jxh Sure, but no where does this answer say it is undefined behavior and defining the behavior makes it sound like it will always work this way.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the different results is that the compiler (here clang 6.0) can produce different code in the main function and in `printBits`.

In `main` it is known that `number` is always 1, and never changes. It is also "obvious" that this can only produce a single `1` in the output. So the optimizer rewrites the loop as:

```
for (char i=64; i > 0; --i)
{
    std::cout<< (i == 1 ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Look ma, no shifts!

The assembly looks like this

```
012B13CC  mov         bl,40h    ; i = 40h = 64  
012B13CE  xchg        ax,ax     ; nop to align the loop
main+30h: 
012B13D0  xor         eax,eax  
012B13D2  cmp         bl,1      ; i == 1?
012B13D5  mov         ecx,esi  
012B13D7  sete        al  
012B13DA  push        eax  
012B13DB  call        edi       ; edi -> operator<<
012B13DD  dec         bl  
012B13DF  jg          main+30h (012B13D0h)
```

In `printBits` it cannot optimize this way, as the function could possibly be called from elsewhere. So there it performs the shift (with the erroneous result).

Comment: Interesting that it wasn't able to optimize in the constant after inlining the function.

Comment: GCC does it too: https://tio.run/##zZBBCsIwEEX3OcWgIMki0CK4MGkXXsAztGmsA2lSktSN9OrGkipCT@AshmE@vPnz1TjyXqmU9miVmToNEl2IXjdDTcjDYQejRxsvGAM1zvaQm52GVntGngSWCrE7n5WbopSrIOUOeA07keWb80DVvfGA1ekoAOuqEMA5siyvjA2Hts4ZRlfcgZZSImMrbt7ezKO2nRFkJmQxC0ODln7dbV1XpSB/ZjtLv5w/6X72XsfJWyiW71J6qZtp@pD49Q0